# Get category fixed in dropdown browse categories

Tags: categories, dropdown, phpmyadmin

I tried to get categories directly from phpmyadmin, but i can't.
then i tried to create this php scrip in public_html

```
include "wp-includes/category-template.php";

$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'pad_counts' => true
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach($categories as $category) {

    if($category->count == 0) {
        echo $category->name."<br />";
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }

}
?>
```

but it's return  Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_categories() in /mnt/env/*****/development/public_html/test.php on line 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you're trying to do this outside of WordPress the normal way? If there is, you could do `include('wp-load.php')` to access WordPress functions.

But that would only be if you *have to* access WordPress externally. Normally your code would either go into your theme's `functions.php` file, or you would add your code to a custom plugin.

Comment: big thanks, i'm trying to build an mobile app for my site, but this script don't return fixed categories in dropdown, do you have any idea?

Comment: If you're using WordPress to build a mobile app, I would check out the WP REST API here:
https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API

 
It isn't part of the WordPress core yet, but it will be soon.